# Is it possible to have a Datacontext class be static using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In one of my classes we inherited a project that is used by the school that I'm going to. It's an ASP.NET Entity Framework project that uses a few API's to retrieve data and is then joined with a local database to give us all the data we need to work will. Currently I have an Instructor trying to convinces us that making the DataContext class static is the smartest thing at the moment to not have the context be disposed at the end of a controller call.

Based on my understanding this is very hard, if not impossible, because the process is action triggered> context created>action completed>context disposed. The action being any method call and even though we aren't using the context, Entity Framework needs it. I'm all ears on this one because I have not been exposed a ton to Entity Framework. Thanks

Comment: Please post a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the design being proposed.

Comment: Your instructor is incorrect - the best practice is to have a short-lived `DataContext`. They probably just want to reduce code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is highly advised to make `DbContext` lifetime as short as possible to prevent unexpected behaviour and errors when multiple requests will happen at once. Moreover one should not fear creating and disposing `DbContext` for each logical scope because it doesn't really cause the application to run any slower.

Comment: Not "as short as possible".  Scoped to a unit-of-work, but in ASP.NET no longer than the duration of a single HTTP request.  If your controller performs multiple database operations in the scope of a single request, they should share a single DbContext instance, both for efficiency, and to enable transactions to be scoped appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some additional context in case anyone comes across this question, (including your instructor:)

The instructor may be associating the single "warm up" time needed for the first access of a DbContext to resolve it's mappings to a cost for all instances of the DbContext, but EF performs that operation once per process. (static) Once that happens, constructing and destructing DbContexts are cheap.

I can think of no reason, or real-world scenario that I would ever consider or recommend a static or long-lived DbContext. Someone might argue that a DbContext with it's cache per-request would take up more resources on a web server than a single instance shared, but short-lived instances should only cache/track entities needed to serve that request, then dispose. (a many small vs. one large argument)

Singleton DbContexts bring significant problems, especially in ASP.Net. DbContexts are not thread-safe, leading to entity tracking issues across threads, and ASP.Net will use threads to respond to requests. The longer the context is alive, the larger it's cache gets. Some might argue that cache = fast, but the larger your cache gets, the more time EF spends checking it for references to associate to query results. This ties up your app server, rather than sharing the load with the database server to fetch fresh data on demand. (that could be async/awaited by the app server to get back to handling requests) EF does not perform stale checks on it's cache so long-lived caches serve increasing amounts of stale data that could be updated by other means. This can also lead to inconsistent behaviour when it comes to accessing related entity collections. For entities that are loaded without eager-loaded collections, EF will still go through all cached entities and associate any that it knows about. This takes time, and can lead to incomplete data being returned.

For example if we had an object graph consisting of:

```
Parent_1
  - Child_1
  - Child_2
  - Child_3
```

then did something like this from a relatively fresh data state:

```
var child = _staticContext.Children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 1);
```

then later did:

```
var parent = _staticContext.Parents.Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
```

As long as lazy loading is enabled (and the Parent.Children collection is virtual) then this should be fine and parent.Children.Count will equal 3 after a lazy load call. However, if lazy loading is disabled or the collection is not virtual then in this case, parent.Children.Count will come back with "1" rather than the expected "0" where no eager or lazy loading was specified or expected, and not the "3" that represents the real data. This can lead to different results appearing between runs, or between debugging and production, and bugs if code is set up to rely on eager loading (lazy load disabled) and someone forgets an `Include`.

That last one can get a bit weird when dealing with updates from different processes. For instance if I have a test that does this:

```
// Short-lived contexts for demonstration /w lazy loading implemented:
using (var context = new TestDbContext()) // represents our long-lived, static context...
{
    var child = context.Children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 2);
    Assert.AreEqual("Sean", child.Name);
    var parent = context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.ParentId == 1);
    using(var innerContext = new TestDbContext()) // a short-lived context somewhere in a call stack, or an external process modifying data...
    {
       var sean = innerContext.Children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 2);
       sean.Name = "Shawn";
       innerContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    Console.Writeline(child.Name);
    var parentsChild = parent.Children.Single(x => x.ChildId == 2); // Lazy load gets triggered here.
    Console.Writeline(parentsChild.Name); 
    Console.Writeline(child.Name);
}
```

What would you expect to see output? "Sean" or "Shawn"?

With lazy loading enabled, the first line will print "Sean", while the second line prints "Shawn" even though the long-lived context has the cached copy with in memory. What about the 3rd line? Surely now that EF has triggered the lazy load for child #2, and it has a tracked instance for an entity with that ID, it would be updated? Nope. "Sean" still. Now what gets even more interesting is that both `child` and `parentsChild` represent the same child record in the database (child ID #2) `child` says his name is "Sean" while `parentsChild` says his name is "Shawn".  Normally EF will not allow multiple references to the same entity. What happens if we add:

```
child.Name = "Fred";
context.SaveChanges();
```

What about:

```
parentsChild.Name = "Ginger";
context.SaveChanges();
```

How about:

```
child.Name = "Fred";
parentsChild.Name = "Ginger";
context.SaveChanges();
```

What happens in these cases, does it update, does EF throw an exception about multiple tracked instances?  With static contexts, tracked instances could be altered everywhere and anywhere in the scope of the application, and SaveChanges could be called anywhere and everywhere as well, triggering all modified tracked instance to be persisted. This can mean that invalid/incomplete changes attempted somewhere can pollute the context's change tracking causing other SaveChanges calls to fail in other areas unexpectedly with no cause of the failure to track down at the point of failure.

In ASP.Net, A DbContext should live no longer than a request, and even shorter such as for a unit of work to commit related changes. (think transaction) Even in Windows Applications, a DbContext should only live long enough to serve the requested data, or perform a high level action.

Static/long lived DbContexts? in a nutshell, just don't do it. :)